# Android drawer transition issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I created an android application with navigation drawer using menu items.

1. Home Screen Activity
2. Fragment1
3. Fragment2
4. Fragment3

In the App, Activity to Fragment transition works fine. But the problem is navigating from fragment to fragment. There is a stutter while transition.

For example,
I opened the Fragment 1 from Home Screen Activity. Now, Fragment 1 displayed fully on Home Screen Activity. Now, I open the Fragment 2 from Fragment 1. At that time, Fragment 1 removed from Home Screen Activity and inserted the Fragment 2. So, Home Screen Activity displayed while transtion.

```
    FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_layout, fragmentOne);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentOne");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Note : content_layout is a Layout inside Home Screen Activity